# Command to list all monospace fonts known to fontconfig

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I'd like to have a list of all the monospace fonts that `fontconfig` knows of,
which command do I have to use?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The command `fc-list` can list all available fonts according to their properties. In your case one needs to search for the **spacing** corresponding to **mono**, that would be **100**, so `fc-list :spacing=100`. Simpler form `fc-list :mono` should probably work too.

Example:

```
$ fc-list :spacing=100

/usr/share/fonts/urw-fonts/n022003l.pfb: Nimbus Mono L:style=Regular
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/semaphor/smftt10.otf: Semafor:style=Mono
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/luximbi.ttf: Luxi Mono:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/droid/DroidSansMono.pfb: Droid Sans Mono:style=Regular
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/bera/fvmbo8a.pfb: Bera Sans Mono:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/bera/fvmr8a.pfb: Bera Sans Mono:style=Regular
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/semaphor/smfptt10.otf: Semafor:style=PersonPillar-Mono
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/courier/ucrr8a.pfb: Nimbus Mono L:style=Regular
```

A good documentation of `fontconfig` library (including font properties and their values selected in the `fc-list`) is available in the file `/usr/share/doc/fontconfig-2.12.1/fontconfig-user.html` (change version number to yours).

Comment: I knew `fc-list` but "_… the spacing corresponding to mono, that would be 100 …_" was waay above my fontconfigosciousness. Thanks

Comment: @gboffi You may take a look at `/usr/share/doc/fontconfig-2.12.1/fontconfig-user.html` (change version number to yours) - there is detailed description of different font properties and their values.

Comment: May I suggest that you add the reference in your comment to the body of your answer? Ciao

Comment: Depending on distribution, the documentation may simply be in `/usr/share/doc/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html` without version number.

Comment: In fact `fc-list :spacing=mono` also works. The named aliases for values (like `mono` for 100) are documented in `man fonts.conf`.

Comment: To get a readable list of just the font names of monospaced fonts, try `fc-list :mono | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sort -u`

Comment: Or, shorter, `fc-list :mono family |sort`